# preg_replace removing a text and tags

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_replace('|[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?]|si', '', $text);
```

This removes all the bb tags from the text. I am looking to remove the persons's signature as well. This has to be done before the tag replacement and I'd like to do it with one regex.

This should be removed completely:

```
[b][color=red]This is my signature[/color][/b]
```

Been playing around with it for a while and got nowhere.

Comment: Share your code to share your problem. Make clear at which point specifically with your regex you hit the roadblock. Ohterwise the answer obviously is: Learn regular expressions first which does not qualify as an answer I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write what you look for as a pattern:

```
$pattern = '(\[b]\[color=red](?:\w|\s)*\[/color]\[/b])';
```

Escape those characters which have a special meaning (e.g. the opening square bracket `[`).

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas how I could make this and the part in my post into one?

Comment: I'd say you can not. As you already wrote in your question you need to do the one step before the other. Just do it that way, there is nothing wrong with doing multiple steps (in fact, multiple steps are often the solution to problems, so doing all in one is bad)

Answer (score 0):

for example something like this should work:

```
/((\s?\w)+|[[\/\!]*?[^\[\]]*?])/
```